# About installing openjdk on Fedora workstation

Tags: java-11

I am confused about do I need to set environment variables after installing openjdk from ***sudo dnf install java-latest-openjdk-devel.x86_64*** as the fedora documentation doesn't provide any clarification about it. Please help!

I installed the openjdk from the it's official repository now I am confused whether to add its path to the environment variables or not.

Comment: What output do you get when you enter the command `java -version` ?